# Concavity of a Derivative from a Graph

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is it possible to know the concavity of a derivative $f'$ given the graph of $f$? For example, I was given this graph here:

[image]

How can I know the concavity of the function $f'$ over $(0,1)$ by simply knowing this? It's pretty obvious that the function $f$ concaves down (which implies that $f'$ is decreasing) over $(0,1)$, but it is hard to tell the concavity of $f'$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You know the second derivative is negative, but can you compare the second derivative on the left half of the graph to the second derivative on the right half? I.e. how is the second derivative changing?

Comment: @TomKern If the second derivative is increasing, then the first derivative is concave up, and vice versa. But I don't have a sketch of the first derivative in my head, let alone the second derivative, so this hint doesn't help me.

Comment: You only need to compare second derivatives at two separate points. Note that where the second derivative is $a$, the graph locally looks like $y=\frac{ax^2}{2}$. So if the magnitude of the second derivative is large, it's very curvy and if the magnitude is small it's less curvy. See https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qzbb3i2vth

Comment: @TomKern I still don't get your point... I know there is a point of inflection at about $x=2$ where the second derivative is $0$, but I don't see how I can calculate the second derivative at any other point.